# На реальном гаджете невозможно получить данные телефона и перейти по запросу post, а на симуляторе всё работает

Tags: http, post, flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:carrier_info/carrier_info.dart';
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sim_country_code/flutter_sim_country_code.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:ip_country_lookup/ip_country_lookup.dart';

import 'c.provider.dart';

InAppWebViewController? _webViewController;

Future<void> loadUrlInWebView(String url) async {
  if (_webViewController != null) {
    await _webViewController!.loadUrl(
      urlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(url)),
    );
  }
}

class Api {
  static Future<String?> fetchData() async {
    try {
      String publicIp = await IpCountryLookup().getUserIpAddress();
      Provider provider = Provider();
      await provider.loadOperatorName();
      await provider.getAndSetImei();
      String identifier = provider.identifier;
      final countryCodes = await provider.getCountryCodeFromLocation();

      final countryCode = await FlutterSimCountryCode.simCountryCode;
      final deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
      final androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      final manufacturer = androidInfo.manufacturer;
      final model = androidInfo.model;
      String? carrierName = await getCarrierNameFromSharedPreferences();
      await provider.loadOperatorName();
      AndroidCarrierData? carrierInfo = await CarrierInfo.getAndroidInfo();
      String? displayName;
      if (carrierInfo != null && carrierInfo.telephonyInfo.isNotEmpty) {
        displayName = carrierInfo.telephonyInfo.first.displayName;
      } else {
        displayName = '';
      }
      final params = jsonEncode({
        "bid": "$identifier",
        "bundle": "bundle",
        "country": "$countryCodes",
        "country2": "$countryCode",
        "device": "${manufacturer + ' ' + model}",
        "operator": "$displayName",
        "proxied_ip": "$publicIp"
      });
      print(
          ' bid: $identifier,\n country: $countryCodes,\n country2: $countryCode,\n device: ${manufacturer + ' ' + model},\n operator: $carrierName,\n proxied_ip: $publicIp ');

      final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};

      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
            'link'),
        body: params,
        headers: headers,
      );
      print('HTTP Response Status Code: ${response.statusCode}');

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
        String? bannerUrl = responseData['banner_url'];
        return bannerUrl;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Ошибка при выполнении HTTP-запроса: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future<String?> getInfo(BuildContext context) async {
    String publicIp = await IpCountryLookup().getUserIpAddress();
      Provider provider = Provider();
      await provider.loadOperatorName();
      await provider.getAndSetImei();
      String identifier = provider.identifier;
      final countryCodes = await provider.getCountryCodeFromLocation();

      final countryCode = await FlutterSimCountryCode.simCountryCode;
      final deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
      final androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      final manufacturer = androidInfo.manufacturer;
      final model = androidInfo.model;
      await provider.loadOperatorName();
      AndroidCarrierData? carrierInfo = await CarrierInfo.getAndroidInfo();
      String? displayName;
      if (carrierInfo != null && carrierInfo.telephonyInfo.isNotEmpty) {
        displayName = carrierInfo.telephonyInfo.first.displayName;
      } else {
        displayName = '';
      }
    // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
    return  showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("bid: $identifier\ncountry: ${countryCodes}\ncountry2: $countryCode, \ndevice ${manufacturer + ' ' + model}\noperator: $displayName\nproxied_ip: $publicIp"),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Даже при клике на кнопку, чтобы вывелось модальное окно с данными, не работает на реальном гаджете.

Comment: еще хочу предупредить что данные не доходят до админки. А через симулятор доходит((